# How to convert a signature from IDA style to code style in C?

Tags: c, string

Essentially I have a function which takes in a signature like `"0F 2F 05 D8 20 ?? 03 72 41"` and converts it to the signature like `"\x0F\x2F\x05\xD8\x20\x90\x03\x72\x41"` where wild card bytes ?? get converted to nop. Also it creates a mask where every non wild card byte gets represented as x. In this case it is `xxxxx?xxx`.
I tried to create such a function but I struggle to convert spaces to \x.

```
void idastyle_to_codestyle(const char* pattern, char* codestyle_pattern, char* mask) {
    int patternLength = (int)strlen(pattern);

    int j = 0, k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < patternLength; i++) {
        if (pattern[i] == ' ') {
            codestyle_pattern[j] = '\x';
            mask[k] = 'x';
            j++; k++;
        }
        else if (pattern[i] == '?') {
            codestyle_pattern[j] = '9';
            codestyle_pattern[j + 1] = '0';
            mask[k] = '?';
            j += 2; k++;
        }
        else {
            codestyle_pattern[j] = pattern[i];
            j++;
        }
    } 
}

int main() {
    char* codestyle_pattern, char* mask;
    idastyle_to_codestyle("0F 2F 05 D8 20 ?? 03 72 41", codestyle_pattern, mask);
    return 0;
}
```

The algorithm is completely wrong but it doesnt matter as the compiler  gives an error at `codestyle_pattern[j] = '\x';`. This function has `char* codestyle_pattern` and `char* mask` as outputs.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. I suggest to add a  `main` function that calls your function with hard-coded values in a way that reproduces the problem. What are you trying to achieve with `codestyle_pattern[j] = '\x';`? You should get an error message from your compiler. I think you have to append the two characters `'\\'` and `'x'`.

Comment: The compiler expects a sequence of one or more hexadecimal characters as part of the `\x` escape sequence used in a character constant or in a string literal. But you probably do not want an escape sequence here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It doesn't validate signatures because it is a waste of time.

```
int hex2int(char ch)
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        return ch - '0';
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
        return ch - 'A' + 10;
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
        return ch - 'a' + 10;
    return -1;
}
void idastyle_to_codestyle(const char* pattern, char* codestylePattern, char* mask)
{
    int patternLength = (int)strlen(pattern);
    
    int i = 0; int j = 0;
    while (i < patternLength) {
        if (pattern[i] == '?') {
            if (pattern[i + 1] == '?') {
                codestylePattern[j] = '\x90';
                mask[j] = '?';
                i += 3; j++;
            }
        }
        else {
            int firstDigit = hex2int(pattern[i]);
            int secondDigit = hex2int(pattern[i + 1]);
            codestylePattern[j] = (char)(firstDigit * 0x10 + secondDigit);
            mask[j] = 'x';
            i += 3; j++;
        }
    } 
}
```